# Login issue in Sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

When i am going to login my site from sharepoint designer 2013
I'm getting one popup window this will show below image[image: Sharpoint designer popup]

But I am not able to access my masterpage, lists or libraries.

When im access different tenant there is no issue in sharepoint 2013,But using current one its give problem to open.

May be any permission issue changed thats why I'm facing this issue, any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to make sure your site collection has enabled SharePoint Designer via Site Settings->SharePoint Designer Settings.

Then clear SharePoint Designer 2013 cache, you can clear cache as the link:
[Clear SharePoint Designer 2013 Cache](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2015-3-Clear_SharePoint_Designer_2013_Cache.aspx)